# Is there a word for discrimination at a level higher than species?

Tags: terminology, animals

[Richard Ryder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_D._Ryder) coined the term [speciesism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speciesism) to describe discrimination on grounds of species.  This is concept is explored by Peter Singer in Animal Liberation Now and described [by nature](http://web.archive.org/web/20230624103207/https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-01977-z):

> Singer rests his arguments on the rejection of ‘speciesism’: a type of discrimination that Singer likens to sexism or racism, but on grounds of species.  For Singer, we might differ in how we treat an animal on the grounds of cognitive capacity, but never just because it is a different species. For example, he argues, if you would be willing to kill a pig and harvest its organs to benefit people (if they were human-compatible), you should be willing to do the same to a human infant born without parts of its brain and skull, which has less mental capacity than the pig.

Is there a word like this but at a higher level than species?  An example of the concept I would like to describe is our tendency to consider birds of less intelligence than mammals, and therefore treat them worse.  This may explain the particularly poor conditions of intensive poultry production despite for example [recent work showing that chickens can recognise themselves in the mirror](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0291416).  As mammals and birds are different [classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(biology)) "classism" may have been chosen, but that is already "taken".  Another example may be the protection given to vertebrates by UK animal welfare legislation, but [denied to invertebrates](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/animal-welfare#:%7E:text=protecting%20all%20vertebrate%20animals) including octopuses and lobsters that [are recognised as sentient](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/lobsters-octopus-and-crabs-recognised-as-sentient-beings).

Comment: I've found the word "vertebratism" in [a paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-2615/9/12/1018) but it's in what may be scare quotes, and sources generally just talk about bias or discrimination with specific categories.

Comment: *Vertebratism* is not properly analogous to *racism* or *sexism* but would rather be analogous to *white-ism* or *male-ism* respectively, if those terms had currency, which they don't.

Comment: @BrianDonovan While "white-ism" is infelicitous, Aryanism does exist, as does Nordicism and some other *-isms* based on the superiority of the root group. But *-ism* is messy in general.

Comment: "At a higher level" than the human species?

Comment: @Lambie Higher than species in terms of [Taxonomic_rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomic_rank)

Comment: @User65535 The question was meant to suggest the OP do more research.

Comment: @Lambie Then you need to clarify what you mean.  It sounded to me like you were confusing "higher taxonomic rank" with the non-scientific concept of "humans being more evolved" than other species or something.

Comment: You don't need a special term for that: there is nothing wrong with using *speciesism* for discrimination on the basis of membership in a cluster of species, rather than just a single species. Discrimination in favour of races A, B, and C, and against races D, E, F, would naturally be described as racism, even though it is not focused on just one race; *speciesism* can be used analogously. Whichever term you use, you will need to explain what you have in mind, and *speciesism* has the advantage of being less distracting than any new term you may invent.

Comment: @jsw29 While that's true, if your discrimination corresponds to a specific taxonomic level of categorization, rather than some arbitrary collection of species, it would make sense to use a term that identifies that level.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, but it isn't associated with just higher taxons, it can be any cladistic group.

> As previously mentioned racism existed in the world since the characteristic distinction of the 1st biological organism.  To understand this concept lets replace the world racism with taxonism.  It is the practice of taxonomy that indeed created the now infamous idea of discrimination in the world.  Taxonism is word created to describe discrimination from one biological organism to the next based on their morphology, development, biochemical or physiological properties, behavior, and properties of behavior.

https://imelynn-dupe.wordpress.com/2015/05/05/the-ultimate-race-against-time-its-never-about-color-but-always-about-comradery-african-americans-lack-this-vital-component/

Comment: The text you quote does not seem to appear in the link you provide.  Is that intensional?

Comment: @User65535 That's bizarre, the first several stories have disappeared. Let me try to dig it out again.

Comment: @User65535 - Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The nonce term *phylumism* has been used to refer to discrimination at the level of a phylum, that is, groupings like *chordata* (which humans are in, along with all vertebrates and a few other subphyla), *arthropoda* (esp. insects), *mollusca* (mollusks), and others). This isn't a formal dictionary term but results like these show up in more casual, often humorous or satirical contexts:

> "It's rank phylumism," PETI spokesman Harvey Foonman says in the release. "Those murdering trout devour millions of mayflies, mosquitoes, and other insects every day. If anglers are banned from the Smokies, their numbers  will increase and even more of our innocent six-legged friends will die. ..." (Brent Conklin. "[Comic 'Release'](https://www.utdailybeacon.com/opinion/comic-release/article_c8ccaa4a-398a-5002-8468-dd6b02441431.html)." *The Daily Beacon*, 23 Feb. 1998.)

> "Is this racism?" "Speciesism I think." "Phylumism this dudes talking shit about all amphibians." "Classism. Amphibian is a class." ("[Idiot frog](https://www.reddit.com/r/comedyheaven/comments/blcm04/comment/emnb1wf/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)." *Reddit*, 6 May 2019.)

> A bunch of "isms" reflect the belief that human beings are no more valuable then deer ticks or any other form of life - speciesism, biocentrism, kingdomism, phylumism, anthropocentrism. (John Leo. "[A Plague of 'Isms' On Your Politically Correct House.](https://archive.seattletimes.com/archive/?date=19920609&slug=1496356)" *The Seattle Times*, 9 June 1992.)

> Not including invertebrates is Phylumism at its worst. Everyone knows that the Blue Ringed Octopus would kick all of Chordata's ass. ("[Tournament of Animal Power (choose which class of animals is the strongest](https://www.resetera.com/threads/tournament-of-animal-power-choose-which-class-of-animals-is-the-strongest.28639/)." *ResetEra*, 10 March 2018.)

These uses most likely come from a comparison to *speciesism*: take another taxonomic layer, slap *-ism* on the end, and use it for funny effect. That suggests at least some degree of generativity.

Comment: The concept and term *kingdomism* can be useful in responding to arguments that the rights of animals require us to be vegans. (But what about the rights of vegetables?) The argument though not the term was put forth [in Samuel Butler's *Erewhon](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1906/1906-h/1906-h.htm#chap27).*